# Let Windows Hello and other applications access a Non-Exclusive Windows driver at the same time

Tags: windows, driver, biometrics, windows-driver, windows-hello

I'm developing a Windows bio-metric device driver for use with Windows Hello.

The challenge is enabling both Windows Hello and custom tools to access the driver simultaneously.

The question is how to enable non-exclusive access to the driver while still allowing Windows Hello to use the bio-metric device?

I've set the "exclusive" registry entry to 0 allows non-exclusive access, but Windows Hello fails to access the bio-metric device in this mode.